# Spoils of War Passive

Tags: league-of-legends

The item [Relic Shield](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Relic_Shield) currently has the following passive:

UNIQUE - SPOILS OF WAR: Basic attacks execute minions below 200 health. Killing a minion heals the nearest allied champion for 2% of your maximum health and grants them gold equal to the kill plus 5. This effect requires a nearby allied champion to trigger. Recharges every 30 seconds, up to a maximum of 2 charges.

How does the gold allocation work between a champion that has this item and a nearby allied champion? Does the ally champion get all of the gold, or do both champions get the kill bounty plus the other champion gets 5 gold?

In other words, if I am a support, is it beneficial for me and my ADC partner if I steal the last hits if I have a charge available (gold wise)?

Comment: Something to test out i guess, as the wiki states now it should give both heroes gold equal to the kill + 5. At least that is how i read it.

Comment: Right, I understand reading it this way, but I can also read it as "The champion with the item GIVES the kill gold to the allied champion". If this is the case, I should only use it to secure last hits that my partner can not get - even if I have max stacks. If it is the way that you're reading it, I should always use it immediately if I have max stacks.

Comment: It states it grants "them" gold equal to ... which leads me to believe both the heroes get it.

Comment: You get the gold for the minion kill... they get that much gold + 5

Comment: So now supports last hit the cannons ;-)

Comment: Try it out in a custom game and let us know how it worked :)

Comment: @brian Did you test that? If so the wiki should be updated too.

Comment: @MennoGouw the wiki isn't wrong, your just not reading it correctly

Comment: @brian I re-read it for the 4th time and you are right. It's actually just talking about the nearest allied champion, the gold earned by the one who last hit should be obvious. Still, instead of "them" it should say "him", i am not an English expert but it clears things like this out.

Comment: @MennoGouw This is what I was thinking, I was also thinking that perhaps the effect occurs instead of granting normal gold bounty.

Comment: @Bob2Chiv I would say no since it says "gold equal to the 'kill' +5". But perhaps i'm still not reading it right, it has been a hard day for me :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Killing a minion grants the person that kills it gold for that minion, this item does not affect that.*

This item does allows you to grant gold to a nearby allied champion equal to the amount YOU get for killing + 5 when you do last hit a minion.  This is useful for champions trying to help out in last hitting minions in a duo lane. However, Spoils of War serves no benefit if there are no nearby champions

With other items "nearby" for friendly effects is 1100 range where "nearby" for detrimental effects is 700 range. This leads me to believe the range on Spoils of War is 1100 but I will investigate later.

Comment: "However, Spoils of War serves no benefit if there are no nearby champions". Leads me to another question, what is the range of the "nearby" allied champion. If you know that answer as well, you should add it.